# Node js variable scoping in post request with a promise

Tags: node.js, post, promise

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
     var foo = req.body + "";
     someFunction(foo).promise()
     .then(function(){
          res.set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
          res.send(foo);
     });

})
```

I made a simple example shown above. I would like to know please is if I have many **POST** requests from clients to this execution maybe at the same time with **req.body** changing on each one, would **foo** in ***res.send(foo)*** cause the wrong response sent to the original client who posted this? Because **foo** is changing in each context so would this cause the wrong value to be sent in response to the client?

Like if client A sends "Hello" while many other clients send a different string, would client A guaranteed to receive "Hello" in response from the server? If no guarantee, how could I get around this without having a parameter in the ***.then(function(){})***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `req` object is unique for each request.  So, there is no connection between the `req` object from one request and the `req` object from another request and what happens with another request will not affect this `req` object.  Each request handler function scope is also separate for each request.

You do have to make sure that what `someFunction()` does is not using any shared variables so that it doesn't cause any concurrency issues, but the code you show here will not, by itself, cause any concurrency issue.

In addition, `foo` is a local variable which is local only to this invocation of the request handler.  Another request will have a different function scope and a different variable `foo`.

> Like if client A sends "Hello" while many other clients send a different string, would client A guaranteed to receive "Hello" in response from the server?

Yes, it would be guaranteed to get the right response.  This is not a problem you need to worry about.

If `foo` was declared in a higher scope (like module scope or global scope) and thus the exact same variable was accessible from each request handler, then there would be a problem.  As long as the variable is local to the request handler scope or a property in the `req` object, then there is no problem.